# MySQL Check for X records within any 24 hour window

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, count

I have a system that stores failed login attempts in a table and records the datetime of the event. What I need is a way to query the database to check if there are X failed attempts for any user within any 24 hour period.

For example, let x = 5. I need to check for any users if at any point in time there was a 24 hour window where the number of records in this table was 5 or more. The 24 hour period could be from current time to 24 hours prior, or could be for example last month between any two time points that are 24 hours apart.

Can this be achieved with a simple MySQL query? Most threads I've seen are about counting records within the last 24 hours which is not exactly what I require.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
yt1.userId
FROM
your_table yt1
INNER JOIN your_table yt2 ON yt1.userId = yt2.userId 
AND yt2.fail_date <= yt1.fail_date 
AND yt2.fail_date >= yt1.fail_date - INTERVAL 24 HOUR
GROUP BY yt1.userId
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
```